# Duplicidade no Datatables.net jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-datatables

Tenho janela Modal que adiciona Endereço do Cliente, o problema é que os endereços adicionados ficam duplicados, estou usando o [Datatables.net](https://datatables.net/) pata listar os endereços.

O processo para adicionar os endereços é executado no client, ou seja, pode-se adicionar n endereços para o cliente e só depois envio para o BD.

A duplicidade ocorre no Cliente, antes mesmo de enviar para o BD.

**HTML**

```
<table id="tblEndereco" class="table table-hover table-bordered table-condensed table-responsive table-striped small" style="cursor:pointer">

                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Logradouro</th>
                                <th>Numero</th>
                                <th>Bairro</th>
                                <th>CEP</th>
                                <th>Cidade</th>
                                <th>UF</th>
                                <th></th>
                                <th></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        @if (Model.Enderecos != null)
                        {
                            foreach (var item in Model.Enderecos)
                            {
                                @Html.Partial("_PartialEndereco", item)
                            }
                        }

                    </table>
```

Botão **Adicionar**

```
$('.btnAdicionarEndereco').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

                var _logradouro = $('#Logradouro').val();
                var _numero = $('#Numero').val();
                var _bairro = $('#Bairro').val();
                var _cep = $('#CEP').val();
                var _cidade = $("#SelCidade :selected").text();
                var _uf = $('#SelUF').val();

                    $("#tblEndereco tbody").append("<tr class='novo' id='' data-clienteid=" + $('#hidClienteID').val() + " data-tipoenderecoid="+ $('#SelTipoEndereco').val() +" data-cidadeid="+ $('#SelCidade').val() +">" +
                                                        "<td style='width:25%'>" + _logradouro + "</td>" +
                                                        "<td style='width:3%'>" + _numero + "</td>" +
                                                        "<td style='width:20%'>" + _bairro + "</td>" +
                                                        "<td style='width:10%'>" + _cep + "</td>" +
                                                        "<td style='width:17%'>" + _cidade + "</td>" +
                                                        "<td style='width:5%'>" + _uf + "</td>" +
                                                        "<td><a href='#' class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></a></td>" +
                                                        "<td><a href='#' class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></a></td>" +
                                                    "</tr>");


                    $('#modalEndereco').modal('hide');
            };
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido, o problema era a tag `<tbody>` que estava no lugar errado, ou seja dentro do laço `foreach`.